# Can't get entire response from proxy C#

Tags: c#, http, proxy

I'm building a small HTTP proxy that runs between the browser and squid proxy. The browser sends the HTTP request to my proxy that redirects it to the squid proxy, then my application gets the response from the squid proxy and returns it back to the browser.

the problem is that i can't get the full response from the proxy, i get HTTP 200 OK ... (just the response header), but with out the body then i have to call receive method another time to get the body. but if i debug my code (which make the application slower) it get all the response (response header and body)
is there any propriety in the TCPClass that indicates to me that the remote server still have data to send to me ?
here is my code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int ServerPort = 8888;
        IPAddress localHost = new IPAddress(0x0100007f);
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localHost,ServerPort);
        listener.Start();
        while(true)
        {
            string requestString = "";
            String respenseString = "";
            TcpClient application = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            string source = application.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
            byte[] dataFromApp = new byte[application.ReceiveBufferSize];
            application.Client.Receive(dataFromApp);                
            TcpClient tunnel = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1",8080);
            tunnel.Client.Send(dataFromApp);                
            while (tunnel.Client.Connected ==true)
            {
                if(tunnel.Available != 0)
                {                        
                    byte[] responseFromProxy = new byte[tunnel.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    tunnel.Client.Receive(responseFromProxy);
                    respenseString += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseFromProxy);
                }
                else
                {                        
                    break;
                }
            }                
            application.Client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(respenseString));
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys

I've done it :

```
while (tunnel.Client.Receive(oneByte) != 0)
{
  byte[] responseFromProxy = new byte[tunnel.Available];
  tunnel.Client.Receive(responseFromProxy);
  application.Client.Send(oneByte);
  application.Client.Send(responseFromProxy);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return value of `tunnel.Client.Receive` and `application.Client.Receive`. [Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx) doesn't gurantee that it will read *dataFromApp.Length* bytes

> REMARKS: The Receive method reads data into the buffer parameter and returns the number of bytes successfully read

PS: You may also want to try [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Core/) to write an Http Proxy

Answer (score 0):

There is no *"there are N bytes remaining for this message"* property on a socket, because a TCP socket is streaming: it sends and receives bytes, not messages.

HTTP defines messages, and if you are implementing an HTTP proxy, you should be familiar with the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616). There are various ways to determine the [lenght of an HTTP message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4), all of which you have to implement to make sure you can successfully receive and send HTTP messages.